# How could I know if files looper finished from checking the files that start at the same name

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-handling, helper, filehandle

Every Meta could have 1 - 5 files base name thus as: :
`1) handling`
`2) vehicles`
`3) carvariations`
`4) carcols`
`5) dlctext`
I check in a loop if one of these basenames is in the meta file - if true I add it to a varible

**`IDEA FOR THE FILES THATS IN THE FOLDER`**

```
name-handling.meta
name2-handling.meta
name2-carvarations.meta
name3-handling.meta
name3-dlctext.meta
name3-vehicles.meta
```

I need a way to check if the specific file has some arttibutes - like specified down in the code - and I want to write the data to the __resource.lua file separately to each file. Example below:

**`The Code :`**

```
    os.chdir(Paunch2 + '\\' + FolderCreatorName)

    ResourceData = open('__resource.lua', 'x')
    print('ResourceFile Were Openned')
    ResourceData = open('__resource.lua', 'w')
    ResourceData.write("resource_manifest_version '77731fab-63ca-442c-a67b-abc70f28dfa5'")

    os.chdir(Paunch2 + '\\' + FolderCreatorName)
    print('Entered the Folder :', Paunch2 + '\\' + FolderCreatorName, '\n\nLets Gooo We are inside the looping :D')

    for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk('.') :
        ResourceData.write("file {\n\n")
        for file in files :
            if file.endswith('.meta') and 'handling' in str(file):
                print('meta')
                HandlingFile = str(file)
                ResourceData.write(f"'{HandlingFile}',\n")
                print(f"data file 'HANDLING_FILE' '{HandlingFile}'")
            elif file.endswith('.meta') and 'vehicles' in str(file):
                VehiclesFile = str(file)
                ResourceData.write(f"'{VehiclesFile}',\n")
                print(f"data file 'VEHICLE_METADATA_FILE' '{VehiclesFile}'")
            elif file.endswith('.meta') and 'carvariations' in str(file):
                CarVariationsFile = str(file)
                ResourceData.write(f"'{CarVariationsFile}',\n")
                print(f"data file 'VEHICLE_VARIATION_FILE' '{CarVariationsFile}'")
            elif file.endswith('.meta') and 'carcols' in str(file):
                CarcolsFile = str(file)
                ResourceData.write(f"'{CarcolsFile}',\n")
                print(f"data file 'CARCOLS_FILE' '{CarcolsFile}'")
            elif file.endswith('.meta') and 'dlctext' in str(file):
                DLCTextFile = str(file)
                ResourceData.write(f"'{DLCTextFile}',\n")
                print('Dlctext is working')
            elif file.endswith('.meta') and 'vehiclelayouts' in str(file):
                LAYOUT = str(file)
                ResourceData.write(f"'{LAYOUT}',\n")
                print(f"data file 'VEHICLE_LAYOUTS_FILE' '{LAYOUT}'")
```

**`Output in the File that printing in :`**

```
resource_manifest_version '77731fab-63ca-442c-a67b-abc70f28dfa5'file {

'f777-carvariations.meta',
'f777-handling.meta',
'f777-vehicles.meta',
'superkart-carcols.meta',
'superkart-carvariations.meta',
'superkart-handling.meta',
'superkart-vehicles.meta',
'wmfenyr-carcols.meta',
'wmfenyr-carvariations.meta',
'wmfenyr-dlctext.meta',
'wmfenyr-handling.meta',
'wmfenyr-vehicles.meta',
file {
```

**`IT HAVE TO BE LIKE :`**

```
file {
   'f777-carvariations.meta',
   'f777-handling.meta',
   'f777-vehicles.meta',
}
file {
   'superkart-carcols.meta',
   'superkart-carvariations.meta',
   'superkart-handling.meta',
   'superkart-vehicles.meta',
}
file {
   'wmfenyr-carcols.meta',
   'wmfenyr-carvariations.meta',
   'wmfenyr-dlctext.meta',
   'wmfenyr-handling.meta',
   'wmfenyr-vehicles.meta',
}
```

what should I do to make it like this ?

Answer (score 0):

## Explanation

There are many issues with the code you've posted:

1. The `open('__resource.lua', 'x')` at the start may raise `FileExistsError` if the file already exists - but it's not needed at all as files opened with `"w"` mode automatically get created if they don't exist
2. Your changing the current working directory to `Paunch2 + '\\' + FolderCreatorName` twice, which is not necessary
3. The first `"file {\n\n"` is added on top of the `"resource_manifest_version"` because you haven't added newline character(s) at the end of the write (for `"resource_manifest_version"`)
4. You're adding two newline characters after each `"file {"`, which is not something you want to do - it'll add two new lines instead of one
5. Your code inside of the second for-loop is not very [DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) - this is not an issue in itself, but it's very bad practice in general
6. Each time you write a filename to `__resource.lua`, you're not indenting it (you're not using the `"\t"` character)
7. After the second for-loop, you want to add a `"}\n"` so that you could have a closing bracket

All of the above will result in your code looking like this:

```py
import os

os.chdir(Paunch2 + '\\' + FolderCreatorName)

ResourceData = open('__resource.lua', 'w')
ResourceData.write(
    "resource_manifest_version '77731fab-63ca-442c-a67b-abc70f28dfa5'\n\n"
)

for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk('.'):
    # Only one newline character is necessary, you don't need to newline twice
    ResourceData.write("file {\n")

    # You're code wasn't very DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself),
    # so now all it's doing is writing: "\t'{file}',".
    # The "\t" is needed for the indentation,
    # "'{file}'" writes the filename (automatically converts it to a string
    # so no need to call `str(file)`) and ",\n" at the end is to fit the
    # format you asked for.
    for file in files:
        ResourceData.write(f"\t'{file}',\n")
        print(f"Data file: '{file}'")

    # Writes a "}" at the end with a newline character.
    ResourceData.write("}\n")
```

Now, from what I see, this is not what you want. You want the names of the files to be separated into different `file { }`'s.

## Solution

In order to do that, we need to firstly separate all the filenames by name and only after we've looked over all of the files can we start writing to `__resource.lua` (unless you know for sure that your file system sorts the filenames). We can use a `dict` for storing the names as the keys and values can be lists of filenames:

```py
import os

os.chdir(Paunch2 + '\\' + FolderCreatorName)

ResourceData = open('__resource.lua', 'w')
ResourceData.write(
    "resource_manifest_version '77731fab-63ca-442c-a67b-abc70f28dfa5'\n\n"
)

files_dict = {}

for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk('.'):
    for file in files:
        # Gets the name of the file (e.g. name portion of 'name-handling.meta' -> 'name')
        name = file.split("-")[0]
        try:
            # If the key 'name' exists, it gets appended to the 'files_dict[name]'
            files_dict[name].append(file)
        except KeyError:
            # If the key 'name' doesn't exist,
            # it creates a list at 'files_dict[name]' and adds file to it
            files_dict[name] = [file]

        print(f"Data file: '{file}'")

# Writes everything to '__resource.lua' - similar to how the previous code sample works
for value in files_dict.values():
    ResourceData.write("file {\n")

    for file in value:
        ResourceData.write(f"\t{file},\n")

    ResourceData.write("}\n")
```

If the file system sorts the filenames automatically, we can just check if the name of the current file is the same as the name of the last file - if it is then just add the file to the current `file { }`, otherwise close the current `file { }` and start a new one:

```py
import os

os.chdir(Paunch2 + '\\' + FolderCreatorName)

ResourceData = open('__resource.lua', 'w')
ResourceData.write(
    "resource_manifest_version '77731fab-63ca-442c-a67b-abc70f28dfa5'\n\n"
)

last_name = None

for file in os.listdir("."):
    if os.path.isfile(file):
        # Splits the name part of the filename (e.g. name-handling.meta -> name)
        name = file.split("-")[0]

        # If the name is not the same as the last one, start a new `file { }`
        if last_name != name:
            ResourceData.write("}\n")
            ResourceData.write("file {\n")

        # Add current file
        ResourceData.write(f"\t{file},\n")

        # Set 'last_name' to the current 'name'
        last_name = name

        print(f"Data file: '{file}'")

# Add a closing bracket at the end
ResourceData.write("}\n")
```